# Get Bytes by number of lines in Excel file

Tags: vb.net, excel, csv, vba

```
Dim FileMemCnt As Integer = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath).Length
```

Hi all,

I'm trying to figure out a way of determining the bytesize of say 1000 rows in a CSV file which may have say 10-20K rows. Once I get the bytesize chunk, I can then split the file into smaller files per exactly 1000 rows. 
Does anyone know a method that can enable me to therefore get the exact bytesize chunk I need?

Below is the code I use to chop up the csv file using bytes in the chunksize variable:

```
Function ChopItUp(ByVal inputFile As String, ByVal chunkSize As Integer) As Integer '1000000 = 1MB (1x6) chunkSize in bytes

    Dim reader As New FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open)
    Dim fileIndex As Integer = 1
    Dim buffer(chunkSize) As Byte
    Dim writer As FileStream
    Dim bytesRead As Integer

    inputFile = Replace(inputFile, ".csv", "P")

    Do
        bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize)


        If bytesRead > 0 Then
            writer = New FileStream(inputFile & fileIndex & ".csv", FileMode.Create)
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            writer.Close()
            fileIndex = fileIndex + 1
        End If
    Loop While bytesRead > 0

    reader.Close()

    ChopItUp = fileIndex - 1

End Function
.
```

Above I have posted a small snippet of code I use that can read the full size of bytes per file, so is there any way similar to read number of bytes per 1000 records?

Comment: You want to make smaller workbooks out of a larger workbook by slicing up the `.XLSX` file by a fixed number of bytes? Sounds like a great way to destroy your workbook! The workbook is a series of XML files that are compressed (zipped) into the `.XLSX` format, randomly cutting that up will leave you with garbage. If you're looking for smaller workbooks, you'll have to open the workbook, then move 1000 lines at a time to a new workbook, and save it. Either that, or I've completely misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, the files are in CSV format.